# How to use JavaScript for front-end and Nodejs on backend

Tags: node.js

I have looked high and low and can’t find anything. I’m a little confused on Web Developement with Nodejs. I have built a simple static file server with pure Nodejs without any framework based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework. I’m able to serve my static .html files and .css files, but I can’t seem to figure out how to serve the .js files. Whenever I include my front-end JavaScript files in my server.js files I get errors like window is undefined or document is undefined. How does one go about developing dynamic websites with Nodesjs. I’m used to the PHP way of development. I just need help getting started with Node.js.

Comment: What do you mean by ''whenever I include my front-end js files in my server.js files'' ? You should at first only configure the node server to do static serving of `.js` files for the client to execute.

Comment: `window`, `document` are global objects referring to the DOM in a browser environment. They are undefined in nodejs because there is no such privileged DOM object. You can create virtual DOM objects in nodejs with libraries like jsdom but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: What do I want? How should I do it?

Comment: I can only guess and it would be easier to help if you posted some of your code! First step is to know what is executed by the server and what is executed by the client. I guess you are only looking for a node static server for now, in which case [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) will do the job and serve your html and js files. Then look at your browser's console for the client javascript's debugging.

Comment: Can't help without seeing both the server code and the HTML file that reports the errors.  Without those, all we can do is make wild guesses.  My wild guess would be that you don't have a route for the Javascript file so when the browser requests the Javascript file from your server, it gets a 404 and your client-side Javascript doesn't work.  But, that's a wild guess because you haven't shared ANY specifics of your problem.

Comment: From the help center: "
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."